# Toggle Component BKG Color in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is a Snack of it ---> https://snack.expo.io/@oiver55/toggle-tags

When I click on my Tag components I would like it to turn green but all others to remain Orange.
Currently the way it is set up, When I select another tag the previous selected tag remains green, How can I set it up so that only the item that is clicked is green, and all others remain or revert back to orange?

This is the app.js code from my Snack

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, useState } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Tag from './components/Tag'


export default function App() {
  
    const categories = ["Tracts", "Timely Greetings", "Symbolic Codes", "Miscellaneous", "Shepherd's Rod", "Jezreel Letters", "Answerers"];
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.trim} horizontal>
     { categories.map((value, index) =>  <Tag title={value} />)}
     </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  trim: {
    height: 50,
    flexGrow:1,
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
  
  }
 
});
```

Here is the Tag component from my Expo Snack also

```
import React, { useState, useImperativeHandle } from "react";
import { Pressable, Text, View } from "react-native";

const tag = (props) => { 
const defaultColor = "orange";
const activeColor = "green";
const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={{width: 80}} >      
        <Pressable onPress={() => setActive(true)}>
          <View style={{ borderRadius: 15, paddingHorizontal: 10, marginHorizontal: 10, backgroundColor: active ? activeColor : defaultColor }}>
            <Text style={{alignSelf:"center"}}>{props.title}</Text>
          </View>
        </Pressable>
      
    </View>
  );
};

export default tag;
```

Comment: No problem,  Absolutely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the working App:** [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/toggle-tags)

**Screenshot:**

[image]

`App.js`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import Tag from './components/Tag';

export default function App() {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(100000);
  const categories = [
    'Tracts',
    'Timely Greetings',
    'Symbolic Codes',
    'Miscellaneous',
    "Shepherd's Rod",
    'Jezreel Letters',
    'Answerers',
  ];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.trim} horizontal>
        {categories.map((value, index) => (
          <Tag
            title={value}
            onPress={() => setActiveIndex(index)}
            active={index == activeIndex}
          />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  trim: {
    position: 'fixed',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    padding: 20,
  },
});
```

`Tag.js`

```
import React, { useState, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import { Pressable, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const Tag = ({ onPress, active, title }) => {
  const defaultColor = 'orange';
  const activeColor = 'green';

  return (
    <View>
      <Pressable onPress={onPress}>
        <View
          style={{
            borderRadius: 15,
            paddingHorizontal: 20,
            paddingVertical: 10,
            marginVertical: 5,
            backgroundColor: active ? activeColor : defaultColor,
          }}>
          <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}>{title}</Text>
        </View>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Tag;
```